# C memory leak with double pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Why it doesn't work? I have a memory leak but I don't know where.
The program crashes and prints random characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** createPyramid(int depth);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("\n createPyramid \n");
    int depth = 9;
    char** w = createPyramid(depth);
    for (int i=0;i<depth;i++){
        printf("%s \n",w[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<depth;i++){
        free(w[i]);
    }
    free(w);
    return 0;
}

char** createPyramid(int depth){
    char** w;
    w = (char**) calloc(depth,sizeof(char));
    for (int i=0;i<depth;i++){
        *(w+i)=(char*) calloc(i+2,sizeof(char));
        for (int j=0;j<i+1;j++){
            (*((*(w+i))+j))='*';
        }
        *((*(w+i))+i+1)='\0';
    }
    return w;
}
```

Comment: I think, you should use `w = (char**) calloc(depth,sizeof(char*));`

Comment: `using namespace std;` <- this is C++. But your code doesn't look like C++. So just remove it.

Comment: Better yet, `w = calloc(depth, sizeof *w)`.

Comment: Also, for any pointer or array `w` and index `i`, the expression `*(w + i)` is *exactly* equal to `w[i]`. Will save you a lot of writing and complicated expressions in the long run.

Comment: And no, you don't really have a "leak", which is when you allocate a resource but doesn't free it. What you have is a *buffer overrun* where you write out of bounds of allocated memory, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: why do people write things like `(*((*(w+i))+j))`   (instead of `w[i][j]`)

Comment: @M.M Also: why do people write both `w[i]` and `*(w + i)` in the same source file, in regard to the same data structure, instead of consistently sticking with one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Since we can calculate how much space the entire pyramid will take its depth before building it, we can simplify the code by allocating a single buffer.

The first layer takes 2 `char`s (one for `*`, one for `\n`). Then, the next layer takes as much as the previous one, plus `n` instances of `*` and a final `\n`. Therefore, the total size is:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + n + 1
f(1) = 2
```

[Solving this recurrence equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)+%3D+f(n-1)+%2B+n+%2B+1,+f(1)+%3D+2) gives us:

```
f(n) = n * (n+3) / 2
```

Now we can write the entire pyramid easily:

```
char * createPyramid(int depth)
{
    int i, j;
    int size = depth * (depth + 3) / 2;
    char * buffer = malloc(size + 1);
    char * p = buffer;

    for (i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j)
            *p++ = '*';
        *p++ = '\n';
    }
    *p = 0;

    return buffer;
}
```

And print it in a single go:

```
int main()
{
    int depth = 9;
    char * buffer = createPyramid(depth);
    puts(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, note that, if you just want a program that simply prints the pyramid, you don't even need dynamic memory at all.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the problem is the allocation of the space for char**. Also, using indexing instead of pointer arithmetic is clearer. This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                             


char** createPyramid(int depth);                                                                

int main(int argc, char** argv) {                                                               
    printf("\n createPyramid \n");                                                              
    int depth = 9;                                                                              
    char** w = createPyramid(depth);                                                            
    for (int i=0;i<depth;i++){                                                                  
        printf("%s \n",w[i]);                                                                   
    }                                                                                           
    for (int i = 0;i<depth;i++){                                                                
        free(w[i]);                                                                             
    }                                                                                           
    free(w);                                                                                    
    return 0;                                                                                   
}                                                                                               

char** createPyramid(int depth){                                                                
    char** w;                                                                                   
    w = (char**) calloc(depth,sizeof(char*));                                                   
    for (int i=0;i<depth;i++){                                                                  
        w[i] =(char*) calloc(i+2,sizeof(char));                                                 
        for (int j=0;j<i+1;j++){                                                                
            w[i][j] = '*';                                                                      
        }                                                                                       
        w[i][i+1] = '\0';                                                                       
    }                                                                                           
    return w;                                                                                   
}
```